# How to evaluate the clustering result of two different datasets.

Tags: cluster-analysis

I know there are plenty evaluate methods can be used to evaluate the clustering result for a single data set, I am trying to apply the same clustering technique to two different data sets and then compare the similarity of the resulting clusters.
**Example**, let us assume that we have  two   student marks  datasets, A, and, B  for the years 2016 and 2017 respectively, each data set    contains  120 records with the following features:

```
student_number
Maths
Physics
Chemistry
English
Biology
Economics
History
```

supposing  we applied the same clustering technique to each data set  for example fuzzy c-means
My question is how to compare the similarity of the resulting clusters.

Comment: see these [1](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28013/similarity-metric-for-clustering),[2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29068/clustering-based-on-distance-measure-between-data),[3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix), [4](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2473161/good-similarity-measure-based-on-euclidean-distance) for some possible answers